# Linkedin API | Publish a linkedin post with PDF attached file

Tags: linkedin-api

**Context :**
I am currently developping an application that automatically publish some posts on linkedin with attached images or not. It works well with simple images via the Linkedin API. But I was wondering how am I supposed to use their API to attach a PDF document to my post. This PDF file would be uploaded to the file storage of Linkedin itself.
Actually, I can publish a post with :

- images
- documents that are available at a given URL

**Specification :**
I have seen the documentation of Linkedin API and I can not see anything to do so.

**Question :**
How can I ask an URL to Linkedin API to publish a post with PDF file ?

I tried to call the assets API to ask an URL for my PDF file at :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload&oauth2_access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

And i am getting the following error :

```
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 100
  "message": "Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/registerUploadRequest/recipes/relationshipType]"
  "status": 403
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently supported on the existing Assets API [Vector Assets Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http)

It's possible that since the assets API is being replaced by dedicated Images/Videos upload apis, LI might introduce a new endpoint for uploading PDFs? I wouldn't hold out too much hope though